# XAMPP configuration failed on XP

Tags: php, apache, xampp

My OS is XP sp2. I downloaded XAMPP (new version of XAMPP 1.7.7) from [apachefriends](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-windows.html) . Then installed. I read many articles and saw videos. but still I couldn't go to the *'http://localhost/xampp'* .Browser says

> This webpage is not available

When I started both mysql and the apache, here is a screen shot.
[image]

As all tutorials on the internet says, when I started, there is a green color label saying 'Running' infrom of the each component. Here there is nothing showed, but there is something in the console.But I can't see any php page in the browser after any related URL is typed. I m an absolute beginner for this.
 **New**
I installed Apache 2.2 manually. Then it runs well and XAMPP shows Apache is in running. When the URL typed 'localhost', Apache's htdocs html page is appeared. So, now I assume that there is no issue in the port '80'(as the manually installed apache is running on it). I want to configure the XAMPP to work with my manually installed apache version.  Any suggestion please ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I seems that your apache/mysql have never started. Have you checked the log (\xampp\apache\logs\error.log)? If there is no Apache error log file then Apache has never started.

Comment: @flec. Thanks. There is no any file inside `C:\xampp\apache\logs` . Then What should I do now ?

Comment: Check this http://www.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=48483. Seems that you are not the only one who is having this problem.

Comment: Click on Start button of Apache/MySql or rebooting your computer. Its seem like just marked run as Services

Comment: I reinstalled and installed xampp,this time I unticked 'apache and mysql as a service'. Now when I start mysql, it says 'running' with a green color background in front of MySql label. but still, apache is not running and,no logs.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no other application is using port 80. (Skype does for example. Close Skype restart Apache).

Check if anything is running with `netstat` in cmd.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't installed skype. There is no app using port 80.

Comment: Would you take a look at my new addition to the question? I installed apache 2.2 manually. It works fine.